# trouble backpropagating through a very complicated function in pytorch - no way to avoid inplace operations

Tags: pytorch, backpropagation, in-place

I want to define a loss function based on a complex series of transformations of the output of a neural network. These transformations involve somewhat complex logic like this that doesn't seem to be possible without in-place operations (see comments):

```py
def get_X_torch(C, c_table):
    """
    _zmat_transformation.py line 57
    C = torch tensor of floats where rows are all bonds, then all angles, then all dihedrals
    c_table = torch tensor of ints where rows are all bond_idx, then all angle_idx, then all dihedral_idx
    c_table blank indices for beginning of z-matrix are labeled as -9223372036854775807
    """
    X = torch.zeros_like(C, device="cuda:0")  # ([b a d], n_atoms)
    n_atoms = X.shape[1]

    # this is some complicated logic - not vectorizable because the variables
    # all influence each other throughout the loop (it's a nonlinear transformation)
    j: int = 0
    for j in range(n_atoms):
        B, ref_pos = get_B_torch(X, c_table, j)
        S = get_S_torch(C, j)
        X[:, j] = torch.mv(B, S) + get_ref_pos_torch(X, c_table[0, j])    # X[:, j] depends on X's current value as a whole!!! This is the tricky step
    return X.T
```

The training code snippet looks like this below. I need to build up clash_loss iteratively with my_function_script, which is a wrapper for the functionality above, but since I'm not doing clash_loss += that should be fine. I think the problem is in the complicated logic above. The error message is that it can't take the gradient because of in-place operations somewhere in the pathway.

```py
           reconstructed_angles = torch.atan2(internal_data_batch_reconstructed[:, 0:304], internal_data_batch_reconstructed[:, 304:])
            if clash_mode is True:
                clash_loss = torch.tensor(0.0, requires_grad=True, device="cuda")
                bonds = torch.tensor(init_z_mat["bond"].values, device="cuda", requires_grad=True)
                angles = torch.tensor(init_z_mat["angle"].values * (torch.pi / 180), device="cuda", requires_grad=True)

                for i in range(batch_size):
                    print(i + 1, batch_size)
                    C = torch.stack((bonds, angles, reconstructed_angles[i]))
                    xyz = my_function_script(C, construction_table)  # very complicated function but written in pure PyTorch
                    # this function cannot not involve inplace operations (see other bit of code)
                    temp_loss = 1.0 if get_clash_loss(xyz) > 0.0 else 0.0
                    clash_loss = clash_loss + temp_loss
                total_loss = clash_loss
                total_loss.backward()  # <--- this fails
```

Is there anything I can do to make this train of logic differentiable so that clash_loss.backward() works? Manually finding the derivative is completely impossible for such a complex set of functions...

I tried rewriting with copies and without obvious inplace edits (see below) but this still doesn't work.

```py
Xs = [X]
for j in range(n_atoms):
    B, ref_pos = get_B_torch(Xs[-1], c_table, j)
    S = get_S_torch(C, j)
    first = torch.mv(B, S)
    second = get_ref_pos_torch(Xs[-1], c_table[0, j])
    Xcopy = torch.cat((Xs[-1][:, 0:j - 1], (first + second).reshape((-1, 1)), Xs[-1][:, j + 1:]), -1)
    Xs = Xs + [Xcopy] 

return Xs[-1].T
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal code snippet that reproduces the issue?

Comment: This snippet is enough to reproduce the issue assuming you know that reconstructed_angles is the output of the neural network. I think it would be impractical to share all the code since it's thousands of lines...Basically, the function get_X_torch builds up the array X by calling the function get_ref_pos, which takes X as an argument. Basically, X is being built up by referring to what other parts of X were at the time. This is the troublesome logic part...

Comment: Is it feasible to create a copy of X for each iteration in get_X_torch?

Comment: It might be, that's a good idea. I will try.

Comment: See above, still didn't work...

Comment: An update: I got it to work by avoiding inplace operations by making many copies, but the resulting gradients are all zero, suggesting that either the model can't adapt to minimize this loss or there is a vanishing gradient problem because of all the manipulations. Also, backward() is EXTREMELY slow. It seems this loss function won't work well for me.

Comment: You can probably accelerate backward() if you pre-allocate tensors for all copies of X. The manipulations themselves shouldn't cause vanishing gradients though because you don't actually increase the gradient path, you just disentangle storage.